# Suggestions regarding these proofs

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, sieve-theory

Severe humiliation by my university's staff notwithstanding, I have taken it upon me to investigate several problems in number theory, and I wrote down the results, see

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/356006809_SOME_ASYMPTOTIC_LAWS_IN_THE_THEORY_OF_PRIMES

and

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/356020318_NON-LINEAR_SIFTING_PROBLEMS

They are not long and require only the definition of arithmetic semigroups, as well as what they call the fundamental lemma of sieve theory.

[Over at Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/177971/how-do-i-get-a-fellow-mathematician-to-examine-my-work-when-i-have-a-bad-standin), it was suggested to me to create a student group that might give me some feedback. Unfortunately, my standing is rather bad, so that I thought I might put this before you.

I'd be very grateful for any comments or suggestions you might have. Should I add more detail? Are there any mistakes?

Comment: Reading and interpreting research papers is outside the scope of math.se.

Comment: I wish I could understand this paper, and give you some feedback. I’m not at that level yet. Perhaps you can ask this post in MathOverflow(with more specific questions).

Comment: from skimming over them, they do look like you do have something to show, but it's not clear to me (but people on journal panels will have a better idea) what exactly you prove in each paper and why it's relevant (in particular how it compares to current research).  
i don't know, but i believe before anyone starts proof-reading papers they have to convince themselves of what's being proven and why is that good. 
as i say, i may be limited in what i can see.  but it was my impression.  on the other hand, i really do think your articles should be taken "seriously" and they do look "proper".

Comment: you could also consider posting on mathoverflow.net, although i'd look up the rules first since i'm not 100% sure it's appropriate either (my actual claim is: consider it, have a look at the rules, see if it can fit, and write a respectful post describing your situation).  there'll be people there who can see quicker if you have something to show or not, and most likely will be able to give advice regarding what to do to be taken seriously etc.